# Macro for formatting names (initials or full name)

Tags: macros, biblatex, citing

I want to write full names of authors in the LaTeX source, but assign different roles to them, and then via macro decide whether to print the full first name or just initials:

```
In the work of \artist{Iannis Xenakis}, as analysed by \researcher{John Doe}.
```

I think in the end I want as output:

```
In the work of Iannis Xenakis, as analysed by J Doe.
```

But I might want `J. Doe` or `John Doe` or just `Doe` -- and I want to keep this decision open, therefore the macros...

I am using `biblatex`, but I don't want to use `\citeauthor` because often the mentions are not directly related to a particular paper cited. Nevertheless, maybe I can reuse some macros that come with `biblatex`?

---

Here is my idea: I see that `\DeclareNameFormat` might provide a good way to define custom formats. But how would a macro using such a format to insert the name into the text look like? Might I use `\citename{⟨key⟩}[⟨format⟩]{⟨name list⟩}`? I understand that `name list` would be my source name as above, but what should I use as key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add dummy bibentries in your `bib` file (and add `options = {dataonly=true},` to ensure that they are not included in the bibliography or used for label creation). Based on that, you can use either `\citename` as suggested in your question or for convenience create a custom macro (say, `\formatname`) that will save you specifying `author` as required name list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{firstinits-last}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{artist}{first-last}
\DeclareNameAlias{researcher}{firstinits-last}

\newcommand*{\formatname}[2]{%
  \citename{fn#1}[#2]{author}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Doe12,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = {2012},
  title = {A macro for formatting names},
}
@misc{fnDoe,
  options = {dataonly=true},
  author = {Doe, John},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\formatname{Doe}{artist}

\formatname{Doe}{researcher}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Although some extra effort due to creating bib entries for all names, I like this approach, because I can reuse the formatting options from biblatex.

Comment: It should be possible to use existing entry keys of those authors -- but right now, I don't know how to switch off any kind of tracking if one uses `\citename` for those keys. "Dummy" entries are at least a safe solution.

Comment: With this approach, John Doe is added to the reference list... Is it possible to exclude it from the reference list. Note that the `options = {dataonly=true},` does not seems to work...

Comment: I have found that if the bibtex entry is defined as type `@customa` (or any of the customa to customf type) instead of `@misc`, then it is possible ot generate the reference list EXCLUDING this type with `\printbibliography[nottype=customa]`

Comment: Note that with the latest version of biblatex (beyond january 2016), this answer must be adapted; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting for the corrections needed.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an idea not using `biblatex` at all:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% define the styles for the first name; these are going to be the values
% for the optional argument of \NewNameType;
% \@style => \NewNameType[style]{<csname>}
\def\@fullname#1\q@stop{#1~}
\def\@initial#1#2\q@stop{#1~}
\def\@initialdot#1#2\q@stop{#1.~}
\def\@noname#1\q@stop{}

% define the user command; the optional arguments sets the format;
% I chose `initial' as default:
\newcommand*\NewNameType[2][initial]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname#2\endcsname[1]{\@nameuse{#2@aux}##1\q@stop}%
  \@namedef{#2@aux}##1 ##2\q@stop{\@nameuse{@#1}##1\q@stop##2}}
\makeatother

% define some styles:
\NewNameType{researcher}           % J Doe
\NewNameType[fullname]{artist}     % John Doe
\NewNameType[noname]{baker}        % Doe
\NewNameType[initialdot]{musician} % J. Doe

\begin{document}

\researcher{John Doe} \par
\artist{John Doe} \par
\baker{John Doe} \par
\musician{John Doe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional styles could easily be added.

Comment: I liked (and upvoted) your's, too.

Comment: @lockstep likewise :)

Comment: I've already hit the rep cap for today, but thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: What about names with initials? Like "John Q. Doe"

Comment: @MemoGarza that would require a little bit more work. Since `biblatex` _has_ implementations for this the other answer probably already does support those kinds of names

Comment: Would this solution work if the person has two first names, such as _John William Doe_? Right now, it shows _J. William Doe_, but the correct solution would be _J. W. Doe_. We can also have someone with more than a first name and more than one family name. How could this solution extend to these cases?

Comment: @DenisCousineau not easily. It is surely possible to implement it but my answer would need some changes. This is easier with `biblatex` which already has styles for the various name types.