# Command for the abbreviated author

Tags: beamer, formatting, acronyms

I'm writing a beamer document, and using the following definition for *author*

```
\author[O. Castillo]{Oscar Castillo}
```

As far as I know, `\@author` returns the value *Oscar Castillo*

**Question**

Is there a command that return the value *O. Castillo*?

Cheers.

Comment: See for example »[Macro for formatting names (initials or full name)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57641/5049)«

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `beamer`, you have `\insertshortauthor` and `\insertauthor`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author[O. Castillo]{\'Oscar Castillo}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\insertshortauthor
\insertauthor
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After a comment, it seems that the idea is to use this to generate some meta-data information for the PDF; in this case one could use `\beamer@shortauthor`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{The Title}
\author[O. Castillo]{\'Oscar Castillo}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\beamer@shortauthor}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @gonzalo-medina, very nice! However, it seems that this commands cannot be used in the preamble, and these are not accepted for generating metadata. :-P

Comment: @Dox of course they can be used in the preamble: `\documentclass{beamer}

\author[O. Castillo]{\'Oscar Castillo}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertshortauthor}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\insertauthor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}`. If something is not working for you, you need to be more specific.

Comment: I tried it again (using the command `\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title},pdfauthor={\insertshortauthor}}`), but I get no author in the matadata info. Could it be a bug?

Comment: @Dox -- What about using `\beamer@shortauthor`?  Probably need to wrap it in the `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`....

Comment: @Dox **jon** is right in his comment, you can use `\beamer@shortauthor`, as in my updated answer.